# AWS CDK Python docker throwing invalid bind mount error when trying to bundle code

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cdk

I'm trying to deploy a python lambda function with dependencies and I'm getting an error from the docker daemon (on Centos linux) that there is an invalid bind mount spec. The error is `"/path//to/my/code:/asset-input:z,delegated": invalid mode: delegated`

The following is what my code looks like for the lambda function:

```
        python_function = Function(
            self,
            id="PythonFunction",
            runtime=Runtime.PYTHON_3_9,
            handler="app.main.lambda_handler",
            timeout=Duration.seconds(20),
            code=Code.from_asset(
                path=str(python_function_path.resolve()),
                bundling=BundlingOptions(
                    image=Runtime.PYTHON_3_9.bundling_image,
                    command=[
                        "bash",
                        "-c",
                        "pip install -r requirements.txt -t /asset-output && cp -au . /asset-output",
                    ],
                ),
            ),
            memory_size=128,
            log_retention=RetentionDays.TWO_WEEKS,
        )
```

This works just fine on my Mac, but trying to deploy from Centos is unsuccessful.

Comment: What version of docker are you using? (show output of `docker info`) My guess is that your version of docker is out of date or you are using the podman engine instead of docker engine. Installing docker from the community repo (instead of the Fedora/RHEL/CentOS default repo) will probably resolve this.

Comment: The version of docker that I am running is `1.13.1`, so this is most likely the issue then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your docker version is out of date. You need to be running docker CE at least version 1.17.04 or higher (this was the version when support for `delegated` mode was added, but ideally you should install a more recent version).

As stated in comments, your current version is 1.13.1, which does not have support for this mode.

To resolve this, you should update your docker version.

Comment: This ended up fixing the issue I was having. Thanks a ton.